# How to add sound to Noty notification

Tags: laravel, noty

I am trying to add a sound to my Noty instance to my Laravel 5.7 app and seem to be running into some issues. The errors I am getting are `Uncaught(in promise) DOMException` and `Get... 404`, but I am using the `Path intellisense` addon in VScode so I am sure it is right. Here is my code:

```
 new Noty({
        text:'Example',
        type:'info',
        timeout:2000
    }).on('onShow', function() {
                var audio = new Audio('../../../public/sounds/appointed.mp3');
                audio.play();
            })
        .show();
```

I really appreciate your help

Comment: Fix `new Audio('/sounds/appointed.mp3')` path.

Comment: @ljubadr the post should be the correct path

Comment: While `'../../../public/sounds/appointed.mp3'` is correct relative path when you use the editor, it doesn't exist on the server (404). Files that are in the `public/` folder should be accessed by using `/`. So your mp3 file should be accessed by using `/sounds/appointed.mp3` (without `public/`). Test it out by trying to load mp3 file `http://localhost/sounds/appointed.mp3`

Comment: Ah, thank you I will give that a shot

Comment: @ljubadr can you post this as an answer please

Comment: done, posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `../../../public/sounds/appointed.mp3` is correct relative path when you use the editor, it doesn't exist on the server (404 page).

Files that are in the `public/` folder should be accessed by using `/`.

Your mp3 file should be accessed by using `/sounds/appointed.mp3` (without `public/`).

Test it out by trying to load mp3 file http://localhost/sounds/appointed.mp3